# PyQT: Calling my own method when list item is changed

Tags: python, user-interface, pyqt4

I'm trying to make list2 to clear whatever it holds in it and assign to it a new value, but I'm getting an error when trying to use my own method `fillListView` instead of built in functions like `self.list2.clear`. How can I avoid it and make it work as expected?

```
class Ui(object):
    def setupUi(self, Ui):
        self.List1= QtGui.QListWidget(self.ProjectNavigator)
        self.List1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 50, 141, 241))
        self.List1.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("List1"))
        self.List2 = QtGui.QListWidget(self.ProjectNavigator)
        self.List2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(170, 50, 141, 241))
        self.List2.setObjectName(_fromUtf8("List2"))

        ### QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ProjectType, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("itemSelectionChanged()")), self.List2.clear) This one works but it's only clear the list
        QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ProjectType, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("itemSelectionChanged()")), self.fillListView())
```

and here is my method:

```
def fillListView(self):
   self.List2.clear,
   self.List2.addItem("TEST1")
   self.List2.addItem("TEST2")
```

traceback:

```
TypeError: arguments did not match any overloaded call:
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), QObject, SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), callable, Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 3 has unexpected type 'NoneType'
  QObject.connect(QObject, SIGNAL(), SLOT(), Qt.ConnectionType=Qt.AutoConnection): argument 2 has unexpected type 'str'
```

Comment: Couple things here... `self.list2.clear` is not a method call, it's an attribute. That line doesn't do anything. Maybe you wanted `self.list2.clear()`.  Also, `self.list2 != self.List2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that when you connect your signal with:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ProjectType, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("itemSelectionChanged()")), self.fillListView())
```

You are passing the return value of `self.fillListView()`, which is `None`, instead of the function itself.

Try:

```
QtCore.QObject.connect(self.ProjectType, QtCore.SIGNAL(_fromUtf8("itemSelectionChanged()")), self.fillListView)
```

Also, in your `fillListView()` method, you might want to actually run the clear method with:

```
self.list2.clear()  # note the parethesis
```

Also, as the other commentor said, you should decide if you want to call it `self.list2` or `self.List2`.  I would suggest lower case.